# Linux 4.3 - Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p1

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to update my custom i.MX6 Board to Linux 4.3, but with the new Kernel the boot process stops at boot and can't load the rootfs from sd-card.

With the old Kernel 4.1.x it works fine with the same environment, only change is the newer Kernel.

U-Boot loads the Kernel from the sd-card, but the Kernel can't load the rootfs.

The mmc-support is enabled.

Boot message: http://pastebin.com/FdQ1KDaW

U-boot variables: http://pastebin.com/7Y8Gacdf

Have I add some feature in the Kernel to get access to the sd-card or something other?

Best regards
Angelo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: Check that U-Boot's `bootargs` variable is the same both times and that the `.config` file of 4.1 doesn't contain additional support (e.g., SD, filesystems, etc.) which is missing in 4.3.